# Parse getObjectInBackgroundWithId returns with no matches

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I am trying to query my Parse "User" table using a objectId to get a specific row.

However I kept getting this error:

> 2016-01-08 22:03:50.476 ParseStarterProject-Swift[6278:3821859] [Error]: No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.11.0)

Why is parse saying there is no results matched when the userObjectId var is clearly found in the objectId column of the Parse "User" table?

[image: Parse User Table]

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    //place checkmark
    cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

    //getting selected user parse objectId
    var userObjectId = userStructArray[indexPath.row].userId
    print(userObjectId) //prints hvPpO9XXtY

    var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
    userQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userObjectId) { (userObject, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && userObject != nil {
            print(userObject)
        } else {
            //print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
  var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
```

To

```
  var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
```

Comment: Or even better, use `let userQuery = PFUser.query()`

Comment: thanks, it worked, may i know why does _User work instead of User? Other table works just fine without "_" , For example, "Follower"